# tkinter's canvas.move makes object disappear

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am running a creature simulator in python 2.7 using tkinter as my visualizer. The map is made up of squares, where colors represent land types, and a red square represents the creature. I use canvas.move to move that red square around the board. It has to move quite a lot. But I know exactly where it should start and where it should end. The problem is, instead of moving, most of the time it just disappears. In the code below I call move in Simulation's init, and it works. When I call it any time in sim.simulate, the creature just disappears. Can anyone explain why?

```
 class Map():
        def __init__(self,):
            self.root = Tk()
            self.canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=1200, height=1200)
            self.canvas.pack()
            self.colors = {
                "Land": "grey",
                "Food": "green",
                "Water": "blue",
                "Shelter": "black"
            }
            self.canvasDict = {}  # the keys are (x,y, "type"), the data is the id so it can be grabbed for item config.
            for i, row in enumerate(land.landMass):
                for j, tile in enumerate(row):
                    color = self.colors[tile.__class__.__name__]
                    self.canvasDict[i, j, "tile"] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(50 * i, 50 * j, 50 * (i + 1), 50 * (j + 1),
                                                                                 outline=color, fill=color)
                    info = tile.elevation
                    if color == "green":
                        info = tile.vegitation
                    elif color == "black":
                        info = tile.quality

                    self.canvasDict[i, j, "text"] = self.canvas.create_text(50 * i + 3, 50 * j, anchor=NW, fill="white", text=info)
            self.canvasDict["creature"] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50,
                                                                       outline="red", fill="red")
            self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
            sim = Simulation([], 1, 2, self.root, self.canvas, self.canvasDict)
            self.root.after(1000, sim.simulate)
```

...
other functions
...

```
 def simulate(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.canvasDict["creature"], 1, 1)

        if self.generations > 0:
            self.root.after(10000, self.canvas.move, self.canvasDict["creature"], 2 * 50, 2 * 50)
            ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized what was happening. I made the mistake of thinking that `.move` would move the object to that location on the canvas, instead it is moving it by that much. So when my square 'disappears' it is really just moving of the visible canvas. I thought that the `.after` would stall the movements so that I could see that happen, but apparently not.